# Mockito stubbing goes away after first invocation of a stubbed method

Tags: java, testng, mockito, stubbing

Java 8, TestNg 6.8.1, Mockito 1.10.19.

This is my first experience with Mockito. I stub two methods in a class, both of them take a String and a double as parameters and return double. I only care about the second parameter in this case.

When the stubbed methods are called during the execution of my unit test stubbing works fine only once. The subsequent calls to the stubbed methods return 0 instead of increasing/decreasing the parameter. I interpret this as if the methods are not longer stubbed.

Here is the code

```
MyManager myManagerMock = mock(MyManager.class);
when(myManagerMock.method1(someString, someDouble)).thenReturn(someDouble + 0.5d);
when(myManagerMock.method2(someString, someDouble)).thenReturn(someDouble - 0.5d);

// the class ClassBeingTested has a private member of the type MyManager
ClassBeingTested classBeingTested = new ClassBeingTested(myManager);
// the method getSomeDoubleValue() will perform several calls myManagerMock.method1 and myManagerMock.method2   
assertThat(classBeingTested.getSomeDoubleValue(someString, someDouble), is(anExpectedDoubleValue));
```

Here is how `method 1` and `method2` are called inside `ClassBeingTested`:
`method2(someString, method1(someString, someDouble));`

I wonder what I am doing wrong. As far as I understand stubbed methods can be called repeatedly and they are supposed to repeatedly return the value supplied in the "thenReturn()" method.

Thanks in advance to all who can help..

Comment: Please post a complete and reproducible example.

Comment: My guess is that the mocking is working, but your test isn't quite set up right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key necessary to solve the puzzle (I missed this in the original version of the question, which I have now edited following a suggestion of a fellow forum member) was the way I called the stubbed methods inside `classBeingTested.getSomeDoubleValue(someString, someDouble)`. This is how the calls in question look like `method2(someString, method1(someString, someDouble));` . You probably can see my mistake right away.

method1 received the value `someDouble`, while method2 received `someDouble - 0.5d` returned by the method1. This is the reason why Mockito did not recognize the stubbing of method2 and the method returned `0.0d`.

I had to rewrite my original "mocking" 
`when(myManagerMock.method1(someString, someDouble)).thenReturn(someDouble + 0.5d);
when(myManagerMock.method2(someString, someDouble)).thenReturn(someDouble - 0.5d);`

and make it look this way so that the actual parameter values do not matter anymore
`when(myManagerMock.method1(anyString(), anyDouble())).thenReturn(11.5d);
when(myManagerMock.method2(anyString(), anyDouble())).thenReturn(10.5d);`

After that everything worked fine. I also had to abandon my "smart" processing in the "thenReturn" method.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify the thenReturn part to return multiple values. Something like -

.thenReturn(someDouble + 0.5d, someDouble + 0.5d,..);

Mokito expects us to provide the return values as many times the stubbed method is called during test case execution. Try this and it should work fine.

Comment: If you only provide one value, that's the value that should always be returned.

Comment: As Sotririos pointed out, They are stubbing two different methods, so you can't use the .thenReturn(multiple values) style.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work for me by having just one value. That's the reason why I use multiple values.